# unable to get rid of unsafe-inline to make my code work for script and style-src

Tags: security, content-security-policy, django-csp

Currently I am making use of `unsafe-inline` in my **CSP_SCRIPT_SRC** and **CSP_STYLE_SRC** which is not a recommended practice. Tried using 'nonce' and 'hashes' but they do not work since at some instances I'm using Django to generate templates and so I cannot use nonce there.
I tried referring to this issue but it did not work as well using media class and django csp helpers:
https://github.com/mozilla/django-csp/issues/119

the model is :

```
class OauthAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'autocomplete': 'one-time-code'}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off','readonly':'True',
                                          'onfocus':'this.removeAttribute("readonly");',
                                          'onfocusout':"this.setAttribute('readonly','readonly');",
                                          }))
```

How do I get rid of unsafe-inline? Any help would be truly appreciated.
For the scripts where I could actually make changes, I added <script nonce={{request.csp_nonce}} and this is working fine.